# how to do a string compare with a makefile's target name

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say i have this:-

```
files := a.txt b.txt c.txt
$(files):
    ifeq ($@, a.txt)
        #do this
    else
        #do that
    endif
```

this doesn't seem to work.
is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orthodox way to handle it is:

```
files_a = a.txt
files_bc = b.txt c.txt

files = $(files_a) $(files_bc)

all: $(files)

$(files_a):
    do this

$(files_bc):
    do that
```

If different files need different rules, you group them separately.  The other advantage of this is that it doesn't depend on GNU `make` extensions.  If there are common operations shared between the two sets of commands (the 'do this' and 'do that'), you can encode the common operations as macros.